# Is it possible to search in javascript object with something like LIKE operator by string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I have an object, and I would like to search in it by a string. The data in object contains that string I want to update that object so there will be just data that contains the string in the results.

I tried this code:

```
let obj = {320936614713847: "Nibaru", 612610972204514: "Slevníme", 633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"}

let matches = obj.filter(s => s.includes(document.getElementById('pageSearchBox').value));

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What is an example of a search string (ie: would you search for "Nibaru" or "320936614713847")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` is not a method which is part of which is part of an object. Thus `obj.filter` isn't going to work. However, you can instead convert your object to an array of values, which will then allow you to use `.filter` out any value which don't match your search query. Then you can rebuild this filtered key-value array into an object using `.reduce()`.

See example below:

```js
let obj = {320936614713847: "Nibaru", 612610972204514: "Slevníme", 633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"}
let searchStr = "Nib";
let matches = Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => v.includes(searchStr))
                    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({...acc, [k]: v}), {})
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not `filter` an object, you can only filter a list.

Knowing that, you can do something like this:

```
let obj = {
    320936614713847: "Nibaru",
    612610972204514: "Slevníme",
    633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"
}

let matches = Object
    .keys(obj)
    .filter(s =>
        obj[s] === document.getElementById('pageSearchBox').value
    );

console.log(matches);
```

---

If you wanna filter by the key:

```
let obj = {
    320936614713847: "Nibaru",
    612610972204514: "Slevníme",
    633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"
}

let matches = Object
    .values(obj)
    .filter(s =>
        s === document.getElementById('pageSearchBox').value
    );

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for an operator similar to `LIKE` in SQL.

You can check the snippet for an example. This will search for anything in the object that matches the `LIKE` clause `'%iba%'`.

```js
let obj = {320936614713847: "Nibaru", 612610972204514: "Slevníme", 633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"}

let matches = []

// Run thorugh object
Object.keys(obj).forEach(kv => {
  if (/.*iba.*/.test(obj[kv])) { // ... LIKE '%iba%'
     matches.push(obj[kv]);
  }
});


console.log(matches);
```

This would be like the SQL statement:

```
SELECT val FROM obj WHERE val LIKE '%iba%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromEntries`:

```js
 

let obj = {320936614713847: "Nibaru", 612610972204514: "Slevníme", 633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"}

let matches = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([, v]) => v.includes("Nib")));

console.log(matches);
```

Better supported version with `reduce`:

```js
 

let obj = {320936614713847: "Nibaru", 612610972204514: "Slevníme", 633965056629062: "Eye of wisdom"}

let matches = Object.entries(obj).filter(([, v]) => v.includes("Nib")).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = v, a), {});

console.log(matches);
```